# Python: why __str__ not call recursive?

Tags: python, string, type-conversion

I have some troubles when convert dict to JSON object. I have this class:

```
class ServerResponse(object):

    status = None
    code = None
    message = None
    data = None

    OK_STATUS = True
    ERROR_STATUS = False

    OK_CODE = 200

    def __init__(self, status=OK_STATUS, code=OK_CODE, message=None, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.status = status
        self.code = code
        self.message = message
        self.data = data

    def to_dict(self):
        fields = {
            "status": self.status,
            "code": self.code,
            "message": self.message,
            "data": str(self.data),
        }

        return fields

    def to_json(self):
        return json.dumps(self.to_dict())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.to_json()
```

I use this class for generate server answer.

```
from server_response import ServerResponse as Response
...
return_data = {}

for (name, content) in result.items():
    if not previous_hashes or client.is_data_change(previous_hashes[name], data['hash']):
        return_data[name] = Response(data=content)
    else:
        return_data[name] = Response(code=201, message="Data has not changed")

response = Response(data=return_data)
...
self.write(str(response))
```

In answer from server I get next JSON

```
{u'status': True, u'message': None, u'code': 200, u'data': u"{'client': &lt;server_response.ServerResponse object at 0x14e9710&gt;, 'service': &lt;server_response.ServerResponse object at 0x14e90d0&gt;}"}
```

Why `__str__` function don't call recursively?

Comment: `content` looks like a plain `dict`, not a `ServerResponse` object

Comment: Yes it is, but converting not correct in `return_data`. `return_data` is a `dict` with objects of `ServerResponse`. Why call `__str__` on dict not call `__str__` on `ServerResponse`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this program:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "REPR"

    def __str__(self):
        return "STR"

x = {}

x['client'] = Foo()

print str(x)
print repr(x)
```

You can see that dict always calls **repr** on its members, regardless of whether str or repr was used on the dict.

Comment: It's explain why `__str__` not call on dict members! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
"data": str(self.data),
```

Stringifying a dict uses the repr of each key and value, not str().

```
def to_dict(self):
  fields = {
    "status": self.status,
    "code": self.code,
    "message": self.message,
    }
  if self.data is None:
    fields["data"] = None
  else:
    fields["data"] = self.data.to_dict()
  return fields

def to_json(self):
  return json.dumps(self.to_dict())
```